# Using clock information in another class

Tags: python, kivy

I try to write a simple clock app. It works well but I wonder, if there is a way to use the methods from simple_clock(App) in Drawing() class and store the information there?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class another_screen(Screen):
    pass
class Drawing():
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("simple_clock_kivy.kv")

class simple_clock(App):

    sw_started = False
    sw_seconds = 0

    def update_clock(self, nap):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.sw_seconds += nap
        print(self.sw_seconds)

    def start_stop(self):
        self.sw_started = True

    def reset(self):
        if self.sw_seconds:
            self.sw_seconds = 0
        else:
            pass

    def stop_clock(self):
        self.sw_started = False

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_clock, 0)

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__=="__main__":
    simple_clock().run()
```

```
<another_screen>:
    name: "other"

    FloatLayout:
        Drawing:    
            id: other

        Button:
            id: start_stop
            text: 'Start'
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "bottom": 1}
            on_press: app.start_stop()


        Button:
            id: reset
            text: 'Reset'
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "bottom": 1}
            on_press: app.reset()

        Button:
            id: stop
            text: 'Stop'
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.8, "bottom": 1}
            on_press: app.stop_clock()
```

Someone press the "Start" button, the time starts ticking and drawing is allowed; "Stop" button, the time stops. And I would like to save the duration of the drawing to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Access attributes / methods defined in class App()

In any class outside of `class App()`

- Use `App.get_running_app()` to get the object, `app`
- Invoke methods e.g. `App.get_running_app().update_clock()`
- Access attributes e.g. `App.get_running_app().sw_seconds`